# Spring upload file using retrofit 2.1.0

Tags: android, spring, retrofit2

I'm using spring for a backend and retrofit for rest client.
I want to upload a file

backend code

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        storageService.store(file);
        model.addAttribute("message", "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
        files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());

        name = files.get(files.size()-1).toString();
        System.err.println(name.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "FAIL to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
    }
    return  new ResponseEntity<String>(file.getOriginalFilename() , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

function store

```
public void store(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("FAIL!");
    }
}
```

android code to select and upload file

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        selection=data.getData();
            String[] filepath={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selection,filepath,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column=cursor.getColumnIndex(filepath[0]);
        String path=cursor.getString(column);

        File file =new File(path);
        RequestBody requestfile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);

        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image" , file.getName() , requestfile);
        upload(body);
    }
```

upload function

```
public void upload(MultipartBody.Part path){

    Call<ResponseBody> callUploader = iBackEndService.uploadAttachment(path);
    callUploader.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            Log.d(TAG,"UPLODER REUSSI" +" "+response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG,throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

Retrofit mapping (I'm using Retrofit 2.1.0)

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadAttachment(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
```

my upload function jump to onResponse but the file was not upload